# Multi-sort Media Wiki Tables

Tags: sorting, mediawiki

I am trying to allow sorting a wiki table that use the "sortable" class by multiple columns.

Eg:

```
 {| class="wikitable sortable"
  |-
  |Col 1
  |Col 2
  |Col 3
  |-
  |3
  |a
  |tee
  |-
  |2
  |c
  |hot
  |-
  |5
  |b
  |apple
  |}
```

That will give you a basic sortable table on the wiki, but it won't let you sort by multiple columns.

Does anyone know of a way to do this or of an extension I can install that will allow me to do this?

Comment: do you mean "sort first column 3, then by column 6" for example?

Comment: it's a great question. Sorry, I have not heard of such an extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find any JavaScript code on the web for sortable tables and put that code in your user JavaScript or site Javascript. This simple one works because somebody has already added code for single column sortable tables which looks for tables of class "wikitable sortable".

Answer (score 4):

Wiki sortable tables seem to already give the ability to multi-sort tables natively / without extension.

After clicking the first column to be sorted, **press and hold shift key** then click on other column headings for the next columns to be sorted. (Reference [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help%3aSorting#Secondary_sortkey) [2](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help%3aSorting#Secondary_sortkey))

I am not sure this function is already there when this was asked, but this StackOverflow question seems to pop on search results more often than the article itself.